# Copying a widget class to functions.php results on a blank page

Tags: functions, widgets

I’m trying to create my custom recent posts widget by copying the whole class from class-wp-widget-recent-posts.php to my theme functions.php but when I do this I just get a blank page.

Everything above the line `add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_custom_sidebar' );` is working perfectly.

My new functions.php:

```
<?php
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

// Bootstrap navigation
function bootstrap_nav()
{
    wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'    => 'header-menu',
            'depth'             => 2,
            'container'         => 'false',
            'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
            'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
            'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
    );
}

function twentyseventeen_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );
    add_theme_support( 'menus' );
}

function register_header_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_header_menu' );

add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );

//Register Sidebar
function my_custom_sidebar() {
    register_sidebar(
        array (
            'name' => __( 'Custom', 'your-theme-domain' ),
            'id' => 'custom-side-bar',
            'description' => __( 'Custom Sidebar', 'your-theme-domain' ),
            'before_widget' => '<div class="widget-content">',
            'after_widget' => "</div>",
            'before_title' => '<div class="widget-title-box"><h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3></div>',
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'my_custom_sidebar' );

class WP_Widget_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Sets up a new Recent Posts widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array(
            'classname' => 'widget_recent_entries',
            'description' => __( 'Your site’s most recent Posts.' ),
            'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
        );
        parent::__construct( 'recent-posts', __( 'Recent Posts' ), $widget_ops );
        $this->alt_option_name = 'widget_recent_entries';
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content for the current Recent Posts widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $args     Display arguments including 'before_title', 'after_title',
     *                        'before_widget', and 'after_widget'.
     * @param array $instance Settings for the current Recent Posts widget instance.
     */
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
            $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
        }

        $title = ( ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Recent Posts' );

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        $number = ( ! empty( $instance['number'] ) ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        if ( ! $number )
            $number = 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? $instance['show_date'] : false;

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for the Recent Posts widget.
         *
         * @since 3.4.0
         *
         * @see WP_Query::get_posts()
         *
         * @param array $args An array of arguments used to retrieve the recent posts.
         */
        $r = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'widget_posts_args', array(
            'posts_per_page'      => $number,
            'no_found_rows'       => true,
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true
        ) ) );

        if ($r->have_posts()) :
        ?>
        <?php echo $args['before_widget']; ?>
        <?php if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        } ?>
        <ul>
        <?php while ( $r->have_posts() ) : $r->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php get_the_title() ? the_title() : the_ID(); ?></a>
            <?php if ( $show_date ) : ?>
                <span class="post-date"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php echo $args['after_widget']; ?>
        <?php
        // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
        wp_reset_postdata();

        endif;
    }

    /**
     * Handles updating the settings for the current Recent Posts widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via
     *                            WP_Widget::form().
     * @param array $old_instance Old settings for this instance.
     * @return array Updated settings to save.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['number'] = (int) $new_instance['number'];
        $instance['show_date'] = isset( $new_instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $new_instance['show_date'] : false;
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the settings form for the Recent Posts widget.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $instance Current settings.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $title     = isset( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';
        $number    = isset( $instance['number'] ) ? absint( $instance['number'] ) : 5;
        $show_date = isset( $instance['show_date'] ) ? (bool) $instance['show_date'] : false;
?>
        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" /></p>

        <p><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Number of posts to show:' ); ?></label>
        <input class="tiny-text" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'number' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'number' ); ?>" type="number" step="1" min="1" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" size="3" /></p>

        <p><input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"<?php checked( $show_date ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'show_date' ); ?>" />
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'show_date' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Display post date?' ); ?></label></p>
<?php
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading breaks because you have copied the class with the same name, and you can't define a class with the same name twice (it was already loaded in WordPress core).

If you want to change this widget, you should copy it, change the class name, and register it as a new widget.